# How to calculate TF-IDF values of noun documents excluding spaCy stop words?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I have a data frame, `df` with `text`, `cleaned_text`, and `nouns` as column names. `text` and `cleaned_text` contains string document, `nouns` is a list of nouns extracted from `cleaned_text` column. `df.shape = (1927, 3)`.

I am trying to calculate `TF-IDF` values for all documents within `df` **only for nouns, excluding spaCy stopwords**.

---

**What I have tried?**

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# subclass to modify stop word lists recommended from spaCy version 3.0 onwards
excluded_stop_words = {'down'}
included_stop_words = {'dear', 'regards'}

class CustomEnglishDefaults(English.Defaults):
    stop_words = English.Defaults.stop_words.copy()
    stop_words -= excluded_stop_words
    stop_words |= included_stop_words
    
class CustomEnglish(English):
    Defaults = CustomEnglishDefaults
```

```py
# function to extract nouns from cleaned_text column, excluding spaCy stowords.
nlp = CustomEnglish()

def nouns(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    return [t for t in doc if t.pos_ in ['NOUN'] and not t.is_stop and not t.is_punct]
```

```py
# calculate TF-IDF values for nouns, excluding spaCy stopwords.
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

documents = df.cleaned_text

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=CustomEnglish)
X = tfidf.fit_transform(documents)
```

---

**What I am expecting?**

I am expecting to have an output as a list of tuples ranked in descending order;
`nouns = [('noun_1', tf-idf_1), ('noun_2', tf-idf_2), ...]`. All nouns in `nouns` should match those of `df.nouns` (this is to check whether I am on the right way).

---

**What is my issue?**

I got confused about how to apply `TfidfVectorizer` such that to calculate only TF-IDF values for Nouns extracted from `cleaned_text`. I am also not sure whether SkLearn [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn-feature-extraction-text-tfidfvectorizer) can calculate TF-IDF as I am expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution. Here is an option that you might wanna go ahead with.

First of all, by default TF_IDF takes into account the entire set of words, not just nouns. Hence, you would need to implement a custom TF_IDF function to apply results only on nouns. Following is a good reference on how TF_IDF works internally: https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/tf-idf-model-from-scratch

Instead of running the tf_idf function(as applied in the above url) for all words of a sentence/document, you can just run it on the list of nouns you've extracted,i.e., just change the code from:

```js
def tf_idf(sentence):
    tf_idf_vec = np.zeros((len(word_set),))
    for word in sentence:
        tf = termfreq(sentence,word)
        idf = inverse_doc_freq(word)
         
        value = tf*idf
        tf_idf_vec[index_dict[word]] = value 
    return tf_idf_vec
```

to:

```js
def tf_idf(sentence, nouns):
    values = []
    for word in nouns:
        tf = termfreq(sentence,word)
        idf = inverse_doc_freq(word)
         
        value = tf*idf
        values.append(value)
    return tf_idf_vec, values
```

You now have a "values" list corresponding to the list of "nouns" for each sentence. Hope this makes sense.